# How to drop a row in pandas which has a certain column value using method chaining?

Tags: pandas, method-chaining

I have a notebook that I am converting using chaining in pandas. Minimally, it looks like this:

```
df = (pd.read_csv("../data/stones_raw.csv", index_col=[0])
    .drop(['date', 'id'], axis=1)
    .fillna({'color':'unknown', 'cut_quality':'unknown',  
             'girdle_max':'unknown', 'fluor_intensity':'unknown' })       
    .loc[:, ['color', 'cut_quality', 'girdle_max', 'fluor_intensity']]             
    .drop(["cut_quality"].str.contains("None").index)  
      
    .to_pickle("../data/stones.pkl")
      )
```

The second drop (`cut_quality`) is giving me a problem. In the longer version of the notebook, it looks like this and drops the row with the desired column value perfectly well:

```
df.drop(df[df["cut_quality"].str.contains("None")].index)
```

However, this doesn't work for a couple of reasons with chaining. For example:

`.drop(df[df["cut_quality"].str.contains("None")].index)` results in `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

The error as listed above is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'`

What is the best way to drop a column in pandas *using chaining*?

Comment: What's the problem it gives you?

Comment: I edited the question but its this -- `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'`

Answer (score 1):

Don't complicate things with chaining..Simple is always better..however if you still want to use here are couple of ways:

Option 1: Query

```
(
    pd.read_csv("../data/stones_raw.csv", index_col=[0])
    .drop(['date', 'id'], axis=1)
    .fillna({'color':'unknown', 'cut_quality':'unknown',  
             'girdle_max':'unknown', 'fluor_intensity':'unknown' })       
    .loc[:, ['color', 'cut_quality', 'girdle_max', 'fluor_intensity']]
    .query('not cut_quality.str.contains("None")')
    .to_pickle("../data/stones.pkl")
)
```

Option 2: loc

```
(
    pd.read_csv("../data/stones_raw.csv", index_col=[0])
    .drop(['date', 'id'], axis=1)
    .fillna({'color':'unknown', 'cut_quality':'unknown',  
             'girdle_max':'unknown', 'fluor_intensity':'unknown' })       
    .loc[lambda s: ~s['cut_quality'].str.contains("None"), ['color', 'cut_quality', 'girdle_max', 'fluor_intensity']]             
    .to_pickle("../data/stones.pkl")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you get the error, but if you want to drop in chaining operation, you can do either with `pipe` or `loc`

```py
df = (pd.read_csv("../data/stones_raw.csv", index_col=[0])
      .drop(['date', 'id'], axis=1)
      .fillna({'color':'unknown', 'cut_quality':'unknown',
               'girdle_max':'unknown', 'fluor_intensity':'unknown' })
      .loc[:, ['color', 'cut_quality', 'girdle_max', 'fluor_intensity']]
      .pipe(lambda df_: df_.drop(df_["cut_quality"].str.contains("None").index))
      # or
      .loc[lambda df_: df_[~df_["cut_quality"].str.contains("None")]]
      .to_pickle("../data/stones.pkl"))
```

Comment: The first one works as expected. The second one results in a bound method of 0 rows (and 25 columns). If you want to either remove or rework the second one, I'd be happy to upvote this also as piping is a different way.

Comment: @hrokr Updated, forget to boolean index the second one.